# Angularjs Unit Test for Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am consuming a service for which i am writing unit test case. When i inject the `service` & call the function from `controller`, i do not get the `data`. I am beginner to write cases.

Here is my code.

StatesList Service

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('StatesList', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/states');
}]);
```

Controller

```
$scope.statesList = function () {
            StatesList.query(function (states) {      
                // Brings all states
                 $scope.states = states;
            });
        };
```

Test

```
describe('States List', function () {
    var ctrl, scope, statesService;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
        inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, StatesList) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            statesService = StatesList;
            ctrl = $controller('StatesCtrl', { $scope: scope, StatesList: statesService });
        });
    });

it('should have practice list to be null', function () {
        console.log('List of States');
        scope.statesList();
        console.log(scope.states); // I don't see any data here
        expect(scope.states).not.toBeNull();
    });
```

Output in WebStorm

```
'List of States'
undefined
```

Why the states don't get displayed. By using POSTMAN data can be seen.

Comment: As a first failure, the controller also receives the service so you need: `{$scope: scope, StatesList: statesService}` (and of course assign the service before creating the controller).

Comment: @JesusRodriguez As i am very new to this.....i added ur code...but didn't get ur second point...How to assign service?

Comment: I am using code as i edited in my question.....still giving me result...`undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StatesList.query()` is an asynchronous http call, so you need to use mock `$httpBackend` service from `ngMock` module in your test. Add `angular-mock.js` to your test config, then try this:

```
describe('States List', function () {
    var ctrl, scope, statesService, $httpBackend;
    beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');
        inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, StatesList, _$httpBackend_) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            statesService = StatesList;
            ctrl = $controller('StatesCtrl', { $scope: scope, StatesList: statesService});
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    it('should have practice list to be null', function () {

        $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/states').respond([{ // ask mock $httpBackend to respond with fake data
            name: 'State 1'
        }, {
            name: 'State 2'
        }]);

        console.log('List of States');
        scope.statesList();

        $httpBackend.flush(); // flush the http request to send fake data back to StatesList.query()

        console.log(scope.states); // I don't see any data here
        expect(scope.states).not.toBeNull();
    });
});
```

Comment: How to call real `http` call instead of mock?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't make real http call in your unit test. If you really want to that, check jasmine's asynchronous support http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: Good answer, helps me too. I'd agree with not calling actual http api, as it is more of a feature to be tested for backend.